# Fishing for easy css questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, fastest-gun

Seems like there are about 1000 people fishing after these questions and fighting to answer.

Please make your questions a little difficult to get quality answer.

Comment: This question doesn't belong here, but why does a legitimate question NEED to be difficult?

Comment: "feel free to migrate this to meta"> if this is a meta topic then *post it on meta*.

Comment: -1 because you already knew it belonged on meta, but decided to post it here anyway.

Answer (score 5):

'Fishing' for questions you have the skill to answer?  The end product of this is that questions in that category can expect high quality, high volume and fast answers, this is a good thing!

Obfuscating a question for the sake of it is pointless and wastes everyones time.